# Get the key corresponding to the minimum value within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, min, minimum, idioms

If I have a Python dictionary, how do I get the key to the entry which contains the minimum value?

I was thinking about something to do with the `min()` function...

Given the input:

```
{320:1, 321:0, 322:3}
```

It would return `321`.

Comment: Data structure awareness day: if you only ever query (or remove) the minimum element, consider using a priority queue or heap.

Comment: What if you had to traverse a list to form the dictionary? Would you still consider using a priority queue as you still have to deal with `O(n)` time to read the list?

Answer (score 949, accepted):

Best: `min(d, key=d.get)` -- no reason to interpose a useless `lambda` indirection layer or extract items or keys!

```py
>>> d = {320: 1, 321: 0, 322: 3}
>>> min(d, key=d.get)
321
```

Comment: I'm tempted to write `min(d.keys(), key=d.get)` to clarify this returns one of the keys to the reader; but in 2.x `.keys()` is wasteful (and `.iterkeys()` just muddies the picture).  What do you think?

Comment: What is the running time of this solution?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'` - what does that mean, dammit?

Comment: @KarelBílek it means you passed in as "d" a list e.g. `[11, 22, 33]`, instead of a dictionary e.g. `{1: 11, 2:22, 3:33}`. 'd.get' is valid for a dictionary, but not for a list.

Comment: what if two different keys have the same value? and they happen to both be the smallest value? how can you make it return both?

Comment: Can this technique be used if the dict values are lists, ex: ```d={"a":[10, None], "b":[20, None]}```, where the min is calculated from d[key][0] ?

Comment: How does this work? What kind of min function is that, I thought min() only took either individual values or lists as arguments. How does it loop over all the entries in the dictionary?

Comment: And what is d? The name of the dictionary?

Comment: @azureai yes it is

Comment: `min()` return the value in the first value in sorted. key designate the way to sort the values. `key=d.get` means the list will be sorted by values of the dictionary.

Comment: It's easy to get the lowest/highest values but how can we get two or more lowest/highest values?

Comment: what do you mean by "no reason to interpose a useless lambda"?

Comment: How can we find 2 min values or key of 2 min values?

Comment: That's maybe worth to point out that it will only work for dictionaries (or containers having a `get` member function). For a more generic version, the lambda indirection would actually be necessary.

Comment: lambda is not entirely useless in such cases. Admitted that for this specific question your answer is the best. But in practise one also often needs the value that belongs to that key.

Comment: Keep in mind that using `d.get` you'll lose the typing information from `d`. In more recent mypy (e.g. >0.9.3.1), you'll get a type error. To preserve typing information, use `d.__getitem__`

Answer (score 80):

This returns the key, value pair tuple after comparing values:

```
>>> d = {320:1, 321:0, 322:3}
>>> d.items()
dict_items([(320, 1), (321, 0), (322, 3)])  # Python 2.7 [(320, 1), (321, 0), (322, 3)]
>>> # find the minimum by comparing the second element of each tuple
>>> min(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]) 
(321, 0)
```

For Python 2.7, use [`d.iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=iteritems#dict.iteritems) for larger dictionaries as it avoid copying.  [Python 3's `dict.items()` is already an `itemview`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13998509/183120) so no changes need.

Comment: Instead of the lambda you can use `operator.itemgetter(1)`.

Comment: instead lamda use d.get

Comment: This does not return the key as asked, but the (key, value) pair.

Comment: Note that dict.iteritems() is no longer supported as at python 3.0.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems

Comment: @kristianp More like `dict.iteritems` became `dict.items`.

Comment: @Texom512 `d.get` won't work with `d.items()`, it'll work with just `d`; won't help when you want the key-value pair result.

Answer (score 56):

For multiple keys which have equal lowest value, you can use a list comprehension:

```
d = {320:1, 321:0, 322:3, 323:0}

minval = min(d.values())
res = [k for k, v in d.items() if v==minval]

[321, 323]
```

An equivalent functional version:

```
res = list(filter(lambda x: d[x]==minval, d))
```

Comment: Your answer is very useful and others probably agree: see the multiple comments for that matter in the accepted answer. However, I needed to come back twice to find it: would you consider proposing an edit to the accepted answer? Yours is actually complementary.

Answer (score 14):

`min(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]`

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> d = {320:1, 321:0, 322:3}
>>> min(d, key=lambda k: d[k]) 
321
```

Comment: @SilentGhost, @blob8108: D'oh!  Copy-and-paste snafu.  Fixed now.

Comment: Fine solution I think, but the anonymous function only adds a layer of indirection: `key=d.get` is better.

Answer (score 8):

For the case where you have multiple minimal keys and want to keep it simple

```
def minimums(some_dict):
    positions = [] # output variable
    min_value = float("inf")
    for k, v in some_dict.items():
        if v == min_value:
            positions.append(k)
        if v < min_value:
            min_value = v
            positions = [] # output variable
            positions.append(k)

    return positions

minimums({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':-1, 'd':0, 'e':-1})

['e', 'c']
```

Answer (score 7):

```
min(zip(d.values(), d.keys()))[1]
```

Use the *zip* function to create an iterator of tuples containing values and keys. Then wrap it with a min function which takes the minimum based on the first key.  This returns a tuple containing (value, key) pair.  The index of [1] is used to get the corresponding key.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε that better?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the keys of the dict using the `keys` function, and you're right about using `min` to find the minimum of that list.

<sub>This is an answer to the OP's *original* question about the minimal key, not the minimal answer.</sub>

Comment: Not really deserving a downvote, as the poster's original question wasn't as clear as it might have been.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: perhaps you can be so kind to notice that the OP edited his question to mean something different, after I answered

Answer (score 4):

If you are not sure that you have not multiple minimum values, I would suggest:

```
d = {320:1, 321:0, 322:3, 323:0}
print ', '.join(str(key) for min_value in (min(d.values()),) for key in d if d[key]==min_value)

"""Output:
321, 323
"""
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach to addressing the issue of multiple keys with the same min value:

```
>>> dd = {320:1, 321:0, 322:3, 323:0}
>>>
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>>
>>> print [v for k,v in groupby(sorted((v,k) for k,v in dd.iteritems()), key=itemgetter(0)).next()[1]]
[321, 323]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `min` with an iterator (for python 3 use `items` instead of `iteritems`); instead of lambda use the `itemgetter` from operator, which is faster than lambda.

```
from operator import itemgetter
min_key, _ = min(d.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d={}
d[320]=1
d[321]=0
d[322]=3
value = min(d.values())
for k in d.keys(): 
    if d[k] == value:
        print k,d[k]
```

Comment: Any idea how to work out the smallest value ABOVE zero?

Answer (score 2):

I compared how the following three options perform:

```
    import random, datetime

myDict = {}
for i in range( 10000000 ):
    myDict[ i ] = random.randint( 0, 10000000 )



# OPTION 1

start = datetime.datetime.now()

sorted = []
for i in myDict:
    sorted.append( ( i, myDict[ i ] ) )
sorted.sort( key = lambda x: x[1] )
print( sorted[0][0] )

end = datetime.datetime.now()
print( end - start )



# OPTION 2

start = datetime.datetime.now()

myDict_values = list( myDict.values() )
myDict_keys = list( myDict.keys() )
min_value = min( myDict_values )
print( myDict_keys[ myDict_values.index( min_value ) ] )

end = datetime.datetime.now()
print( end - start )



# OPTION 3

start = datetime.datetime.now()

print( min( myDict, key=myDict.get ) )

end = datetime.datetime.now()
print( end - start )
```

Sample output:

```
#option 1
236230
0:00:14.136808

#option 2
236230
0:00:00.458026

#option 3
236230
0:00:00.824048
```

Answer (score 2):

To create an orderable class you have to override six special functions, so that it would be called by the min() function.

These methods are`__lt__ , __le__, __gt__, __ge__, __eq__ , __ne__` in order they are less than, less than or equal, greater than, greater than or equal, equal, not equal.

For example, you should implement `__lt__` as follows:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
  return self.comparable_value < other.comparable_value
```

Then you can use the min function as follows:

```
minValue = min(yourList, key=(lambda k: yourList[k]))
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Or `__getitem__`:

```
>>> d = {320: 1, 321: 0, 322: 3}
>>> min(d, key=d.__getitem__)
321
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dic = {320:1, 321:0, 322:3}
min_value = sorted(my_dic, key=lambda k: my_dic[k])[0]
print(min_value)
```

> A solution with only the sorted method.

1. I sorted values from smallest to largest with sorted method
2. When we get the first index, it gives the smallest key.

Answer (score -1):

```
# python 
d={320:1, 321:0, 322:3}
reduce(lambda x,y: x if d[x]<=d[y] else y, d.iterkeys())
  321
```

Comment: 1)Reduce is generally slower than itertools. 2)Most implementations of reduce can be done simpler with any or all. 3)I am a giant mouthpiece for GvR. 4)The operator module makes most simple lambdas unnecessary, and complex lambdas should be defined as real functions anyway. Maybe I'm just scared of functional programming. ;)

Comment: @miked: tell me more. what's gvr and what's the operator module? could you post links? i may know others, but i'm still just an intermediate in python. willing to learn! :-)

Comment: GvR is Guido van Rossum, Python's benevolent dictator for life. Here's a [five year old post](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) from him explaining why lisp-isms (map,filter,reduce,lambda) don't have much of a place in python going forward, and those reasons are still true today. The operator module has replacements for [extracting members](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter): "lambda x: x[1]" compared to "itemgetter(1)" is a character longer and arguably takes longer to understand. I'm out of space, but ask questions!

Comment: @miked: want first bite at the apple? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292481/most-important-python-optimizations

Comment: Their is really no need to reimplement something built in (`min()`).