# How to return a list of keys corresponding to the smallest value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Let say I have a dictionary of total of fruits:

```
Fruits = {"apple":8, "banana":3, "lemon":5, "pineapple":2,}
```

And I want the output to be

```
["pineapple"]
```

because pineapple has the least value. Or if I have this:

```
Colour = {"blue":5, "green":2, "purple":6, "red":2}
```

The output will be:

```
["green","red"]
```

because green and red has both the least value.

So how do I return the smallest value in dictionary?

Comment: Helpful link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282823/get-key-with-the-least-value-from-a-dictionary

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Can do it as a two-pass:

```
>>> colour
{'blue': 5, 'purple': 6, 'green': 2, 'red': 2}
>>> min_val = min(colour.itervalues())
>>> [k for k, v in colour.iteritems() if v == min_val]
['green', 'red']
```

1. Find the min value of the dict's values
2. Then go back over and extract the key where it's that value...

An alternative (requires some imports, and means you could take the n many if wanted) - this code just takes the first though (which would be the min value):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

ordered = sorted(colour.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))
bykey = groupby(ordered, key=itemgetter(1))
print map(itemgetter(0), next(bykey)[1])
# ['green', 'red']
```

Comment: What if you have a dict of lists instead?

Answer (score 4):

I would say that the best option is to make two passes:

```
min_value = min(dict.values())
result = [key for key, value in dict.iteritems() if value == min_value]
```

You can make a single pass by looping explicitly:

```
result = []
min_value = None
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    if min_value is None or value < min_value:
        min_value = value
        result = []
    if value == min_value:
        result.append(key)
```

but this is going to be slower (except may be in PyPy)

Comment: +1 For the most efficient solution (2nd one), another way that removes the need to check for `None` is setting `min_value = float('inf')`. It's nicer IMHO

Comment: Since values are numerical, the code would be simpler with `min_value = float("inf")` at the beginning. There is no need to test for None later.

Comment: @EOL: correct. That would also work if all elements are +inf

Answer (score 1):

Just an option:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

Fruits = {"apple":8, "banana":3, "lemon":5, "pineapple":2,}
Colour = {"blue":5, "green":2, "purple":6, "red":2}


def get_res(dVals):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in dVals.items():
        res[v].append(k)
    return min(res.items(), key=itemgetter(0))[1]

print get_res(Fruits)
print get_res(Colour)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see, it works with a dirty lambda function like this:

```
min(Fruits,key=lambda x:Fruits[x])
```

I guess it will return only one value but still quite nice. :)

Comment: `min(fruits, key=fruits.get)` is even nicer: there is no need for the added layer of indirection of the lambda.

Comment: Please explain how does this magic work! And how does it compare to other methods, like with 'operator' import.

Answer (score 1):

```
ans =[min(Fruits, key=Fruits.get)]
print(ans)
```

Above code Finds the key corresponding to the minimum value within a dictionary.
It finds the key of dictionary(Fruits) where the function Fruits.get(key) is equivalent to Fruits[key] returns lowest comparable value.

For the multiple keys with minimum value, first get the minimum value from the dictionary Fruits and then get the corresponding keys from the dictionary using for loop as shown below.

```
min_value= min(Fruits.values())
ans= [key for key in Fruits if Fruits[key]==min_value]
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = {"blue":5, "green":2, "purple":6, "red":2}# {"apple":8, "banana":3, "lemon":5, "pineapple":2,}

sorted_items = sorted(colors.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])
print (sorted_items)


min_val = sorted_items[0][1]

for t in sorted_items:
    if t[1] == min_val:
        print(t[0])
    else:
        break




--output:--
[('green', 2), ('red', 2), ('blue', 5), ('purple', 6)]

green
red
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
def getmin(dictionary):
    gen = ((j,i) for i,j in dictionary.iteritems())
    items = sorted(gen)
    minimum = items.pop(0)
    rest = itertools.takewhile(lambda item:item[0]==minimum[0],items)
    return [x[1] for x in itertools.chain([minimum],rest)]
```

This method uses a [schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to take advantage of native sorting (no key required).
It sorts the items based on the value of the key in the dictionary, takes the minimum, and takes all of the ones that are the same.

Comment: Um... why do you think it's a good thing to have a schwartzian transform when `key` was made so that you don't need to do that any more

Answer (score -1):

```
minimum = []      # creates empty list for all possible minimum keys
def min(dict):    # defines a function called minimum taking a argument dict
    m= min(dict.values())     # stating minimum value in dict
    for key, values in dict.items():     # iterating through key and values in items of dictionary
        if value == m:        # checking if value is minimum
            minimum.append(key)      # appending minimum values to the empty list created
    return minimum         # returning the list
```

Comment: The function can't use the built-in `min` if the function itself is called `min`. You are created unlimited recursion. The fix is simple; rename the function (but you will also need to move the global variable so it's declared inside the function).