# How can I find the most negative key in a python dictionary?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the most positive and most negative values in the dictionary imdb_dict:

```
imdb_dict = {'the': '0.0490972013402',
 'and': '0.201363575849',
 'a': '0.0333946807184',
 'of': '0.099837669572',
 'to': '-0.0790210365788',
 'is': '0.188660139871',
 'it': '0.00712569582356',
 'in': '0.109215821589',
 'i': '-0.154986397986'}
```

Using the code found here:  [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary/12343826)

I can obtain the maximum value of the dictionary using:

```py
import operator
max(imdb_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

However, I cannot find a way to get the most negative value in the dictionary as using min shows the value closest to 0.  Is there a way to modify the operator to get the maximum negative value or an easier way to accomplish the same?

Comment: your values are strings. min will work fine if they are converted to numbers for numerical comparison.

Comment: [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)?

Comment: `val = min(float(val) for val in imdb_dict.values())`

Comment: If you are looking for value, then take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099112/how-to-return-smallest-value-in-dictionary

Comment: `min(imdb_dict.items(), key=lambda x: float(x[1]))`

Comment: thank you for catching my blunder.  I completely missed the datatype that was being imported from the text file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that the values are `strings`, so the ordering is lexicographical. You'd need a `lambda` function to take the `min` over the values in the dictionary as `floats`:

```
min(imdb_dict.items(), key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
# ('i', '-0.154986397986')
```

---

Note that by doing:

```
'-0.154986397986' < '-0.0790210365788'
```

You get `False`, as this is just checking what position a given character occupies in the `ASCII` table to discern which is the lowest. Hence the character that will decide which string is lowest will be where the first difference takes place, in this case the digit right after the dot, i.e `1` and `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
imdb_dict = {'the': '0.0490972013402',
 'and': '0.201363575849',
 'a': '0.0333946807184',
 'of': '0.099837669572',
 'to': '-0.0790210365788',
 'is': '0.188660139871',
 'it': '0.00712569582356',
 'in': '0.109215821589',
 'i': '-0.154986397986'}

min_val = min(map(lambda x:float(x), imdb_dict.values()))
key = [i for i in imdb_dict.keys() if imdb_dict[i]==min_val]

print(key)
# output 'i'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
imdb_dict = {'the': '0.0490972013402',
             'and': '0.201363575849',
             'a': '0.0333946807184',
             'of': '0.099837669572',
             'to': '-0.0790210365788',
             'is': '0.188660139871',
             'it': '0.00712569582356',
             'in': '0.109215821589',
             'i': '-0.154986397986'}

for i, k in enumerate(imdb_dict.keys()):
    if i == 0:
        _min = (float(imdb_dict[k]), k)
    else:
        if float(imdb_dict[k]) < _min[0]:
            _min = (float(imdb_dict[k]), k)
print(_min)
```

output

```
(-0.154986397986, 'i')
```