# Nested Json to pandas DataFrame with specific format

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

I need to format the contents of a Json file in a certain format in a pandas DataFrame so that I can run pandassql to transform the data and run it through a scoring model.

`file = C:\scoring_model\json.js`   (contents of 'file' are below)

```
{
"response":{
  "version":"1.1",
  "token":"dsfgf",
   "body":{
     "customer":{
         "customer_id":"1234567",
         "verified":"true"
       },
     "contact":{
         "email":"mr@abc.com",
         "mobile_number":"0123456789"
      },
     "personal":{
         "gender": "m",
         "title":"Dr.",
         "last_name":"Muster",
         "first_name":"Max",
         "family_status":"single",
         "dob":"1985-12-23",
     }
   }
 }
```

I need the dataframe to look like this (obviously all values on same row, tried to format it best as possible for this question):

```
version | token | customer_id | verified | email      | mobile_number | gender |
1.1     | dsfgf | 1234567     | true     | mr@abc.com | 0123456789    | m      |

title | last_name | first_name |family_status | dob
Dr.   | Muster    | Max        | single       | 23.12.1985
```

I have looked at all the other questions on this topic, have tried various ways to load Json file into pandas

```
with open(r'C:\scoring_model\json.js', 'r') as f:
    c = pd.read_json(f.read())

with open(r'C:\scoring_model\json.js', 'r') as f:
    c = f.readlines()
```

tried `pd.Panel()` in this solution [Python Pandas: How to split a sorted dictionary in a column of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742975/python-pandas-how-to-split-a-sorted-dictionary-in-a-column-of-a-dataframe) with dataframe results from `[yo = f.readlines()]`. I thought about trying to split contents of each cell based on `("")` and find a way to put the split contents into different columns but no luck so far.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you load in the entire json as a dict (or list) e.g. using `json.load`, you can use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
In [11]: d = {"response": {"body": {"contact": {"email": "mr@abc.com", "mobile_number": "0123456789"}, "personal": {"last_name": "Muster", "gender": "m", "first_name": "Max", "dob": "1985-12-23", "family_status": "single", "title": "Dr."}, "customer": {"verified": "true", "customer_id": "1234567"}}, "token": "dsfgf", "version": "1.1"}}

In [12]: df = pd.json_normalize(d)

In [13]: df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
        email mobile_number customer_id verified         dob family_status first_name gender last_name title  token version
0  mr@abc.com    0123456789     1234567     true  1985-12-23        single        Max      m    Muster   Dr.  dsfgf     1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier if you deserialize the JSON using the built-in `json` module first (instead of `pd.read_json()`) and then flatten it using `pd.json_normalize()`.

```py
# deserialize
with open(r'C:\scoring_model\json.js', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# flatten
df = pd.json_normalize(d)
```

If a dictionary is passed to `json_normalize()`, it's flattened into a single row, but if a list is passed to it, it's flattened into multiple rows. So if the nested structure contains only key-value pairs, `pd.json_normalize()` with no parameters suffices to flatten it.

---

However, if the data contains a list (JSON array in the nesting in the file), then passing `record_path=` argument to let pandas find the path to the records. For example, if the data is like the following (notice how the value under `"body"` is a list, i.e. a list of records):

```py
data = {
    "response":[
        {
            "version":"1.1",
            "customer": {"id": "1234567", "verified":"true"},
            "body":[
                {"email":"mr@abc.com", "mobile_number":"0123456789"},
                {"email":"ms@abc.com", "mobile_number":"9876543210"}
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "version":"1.2",
            "customer": {"id": "0987654", "verified":"true"},
            "body":[
                {"email":"master@abc.com", "mobile_number":"9999999999"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

then you can pass `record_path=` to let the program know that the records are under `"body"` and pass `meta=` to set the path to the metadata. Note how in `"body"`, `"version"` and `"customer"` are in the same level in the data but `"id"` is nested one level more so you need to pass a list to get the value under `"id"`.

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(data['response'], record_path=['body'], meta=['version', ['customer', 'id']])
```

[image: res]