# convert json to csv with python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have some very large json files which i need to convert (The largest one is 500 mb). The online tools only support a small size which is not suitable for me. So I looked to stackoverflow to look for scripts which may work for me. The found this one:

```
import csv
import json

infile = open("test_user.json","r")
outfile = open ("test_user.csv","w")

writer = csv.writer(outfile)

for row in infile:
  data = json.loads(row)
  writer.writerow(data)
```

Here is a link one of my json files: https://pastebin.com/xpzeJmug

```
[
    {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "id": 433266666479562750,
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "source": "<a href=\"http://www.apple.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">iOS</a>",
        "retweeted": false,
        "coordinates": null,
        "entities": {
            "symbols": [],
            "user_mentions": [],
            "hashtags": [
                {
                    "indices": [
                        38,
                        43
                    ],
                    "text": "IMDb"
                }
            ],
            "urls": [
                {
                    "url": "http://tw.co/LTiHcO3XH2",
                    "indices": [
                        44,
                        66
                    ],
                    "expanded_url": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0993846",
                    "display_url": "imdb.com/title/tt0993846"
                }
            ]
        },
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "retweet_count": 0,
        "id_str": "433266666479562753",
        "favorited": false,
        "user": {
            "follow_request_sent": false,
            "profile_use_background_image": true,
            "id": 182591357,
            "verified": false,
            "profile_text_color": "333333",
            "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/430409335710416897/pwV3muOK_normal.jpeg",
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
            "is_translator": false,
            "geo_enabled": true,
            "entities": {
                "description": {
                    "urls": []
                }
            },
            "followers_count": 363,
            "protected": false,
            "location": "Turkey",
            "default_profile_image": false,
            "id_str": "182591357",
            "lang": "tr",
            "utc_offset": 7200,
            "statuses_count": 23921,
            "description": "@Besiktas, I Love House Music.",
            "friends_count": 238,
            "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
            "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/430409335710416897/pwV3muOK_normal.jpeg",
            "notifications": false,
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/660819655/mbxstu4fqnkll8b5kyu7.jpeg",
            "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
            "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/182591357/1391607536",
            "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/660819655/mbxstu4fqnkll8b5kyu7.jpeg",
            "name": "Metin Haşal",
            "is_translation_enabled": false,
            "profile_background_tile": true,
            "favourites_count": 3,
            "screen_name": "metinhasal",
            "url": null,
            "created_at": "Tue Aug 24 23:30:11 +0000 2010",
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "time_zone": "Istanbul",
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
            "default_profile": false,
            "following": false,
            "listed_count": 0
        },
        "geo": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "possibly_sensitive": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "created_at": "Tue Feb 11 15:49:57 +0000 2014",
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "place": null,
        "metadata": {
            "iso_language_code": "en",
            "result_type": "recent"
        }
    },
    {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "id": 433266923489730560,
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "source": "<a href=\"http://www.apple.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">iOS</a>",
        "retweeted": false,
        "coordinates": null,
        "entities": {
            "symbols": [],
            "user_mentions": [],
            "hashtags": [
                {
                    "indices": [
                        53,
                        58
                    ],
                    "text": "IMDb"
                }
            ],
            "urls": [
                {
                    "url": "http://tw.co/IAWzT6Mmp1",
                    "indices": [
                        30,
                        52
                    ],
                    "expanded_url": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0387877",
                    "display_url": "imdb.com/title/tt0387877"
                }
            ]
        },
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "retweet_count": 0,
        "id_str": "433266923489730560",
        "favorited": false,
        "user": {
            "follow_request_sent": false,
            "profile_use_background_image": true,
            "id": 249246669,
            "verified": false,
            "profile_text_color": "333333",
            "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2551826686/image_normal.jpg",
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
            "is_translator": false,
            "geo_enabled": true,
            "entities": {
                "url": {
                    "urls": [
                        {
                            "url": "http://tw.co/VhnKdhkDbZ",
                            "indices": [
                                0,
                                22
                            ],
                            "expanded_url": "http://www.vimeo.com/bolelof",
                            "display_url": "vimeo.com/bolelof"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "description": {
                    "urls": []
                }
            },
            "followers_count": 787,
            "protected": false,
            "location": "Moscow City Mufuka!",
            "default_profile_image": false,
            "id_str": "249246669",
            "lang": "en",
            "utc_offset": -18000,
            "statuses_count": 1969,
            "description": "Заядлый турист, маньяк-велосипедист, любитель тату-портаков и всей музыки на свете. Ведущий 'афиши' на мск-24. Хороший парень и возможно ваш друг.",
            "friends_count": 108,
            "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
            "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2551826686/image_normal.jpg",
            "notifications": false,
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
            "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
            "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
            "name": "болелов борис",
            "is_translation_enabled": false,
            "profile_background_tile": false,
            "favourites_count": 0,
            "screen_name": "bolelof_boris",
            "url": "http://tw.co/VhnKdhkDbZ",
            "created_at": "Tue Feb 08 17:26:01 +0000 2011",
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "time_zone": "Quito",
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
            "default_profile": true,
            "following": false,
            "listed_count": 27
        },
        "geo": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "possibly_sensitive": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "created_at": "Tue Feb 11 15:50:58 +0000 2014",
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "place": null,
        "metadata": {
            "iso_language_code": "en",
            "result_type": "recent"
        }
    },
    {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "id": 433267603868762100,
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "source": "<a href=\"http://www.apple.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">iOS</a>",
        "retweeted": false,
        "coordinates": null,
        "entities": {
            "symbols": [],
            "user_mentions": [],
            "hashtags": [
                {
                    "indices": [
                        45,
                        50
                    ],
                    "text": "IMDb"
                }
            ],
            "urls": [
                {
                    "url": "http://tw.co/Mv56yMkFQ2",
                    "indices": [
                        22,
                        44
                    ],
                    "expanded_url": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2193215",
                    "display_url": "imdb.com/title/tt2193215"
                }
            ]
        },
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "retweet_count": 0,
        "id_str": "433267603868762112",
        "favorited": false,
        "user": {
            "follow_request_sent": false,
            "profile_use_background_image": true,
            "id": 249246669,
            "verified": false,
            "profile_text_color": "333333",
            "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2551826686/image_normal.jpg",
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
            "is_translator": false,
            "geo_enabled": true,
            "entities": {
                "url": {
                    "urls": [
                        {
                            "url": "http://tw.co/VhnKdhkDbZ",
                            "indices": [
                                0,
                                22
                            ],
                            "expanded_url": "http://www.vimeo.com/bolelof",
                            "display_url": "vimeo.com/bolelof"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "description": {
                    "urls": []
                }
            },
            "followers_count": 787,
            "protected": false,
            "location": "Moscow City Mufuka!",
            "default_profile_image": false,
            "id_str": "249246669",
            "lang": "en",
            "utc_offset": -18000,
            "statuses_count": 1969,
            "description": "Заядлый турист, маньяк-велосипедист, любитель тату-портаков и всей музыки на свете. Ведущий 'афиши' на мск-24. Хороший парень и возможно ваш друг.",
            "friends_count": 108,
            "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
            "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2551826686/image_normal.jpg",
            "notifications": false,
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
            "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
            "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
            "name": "болелов борис",
            "is_translation_enabled": false,
            "profile_background_tile": false,
            "favourites_count": 0,
            "screen_name": "bolelof_boris",
            "url": "http://tw.co/VhnKdhkDbZ",
            "created_at": "Tue Feb 08 17:26:01 +0000 2011",
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "time_zone": "Quito",
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
            "default_profile": true,
            "following": false,
            "listed_count": 27
        },
        "geo": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "possibly_sensitive": false,
        "lang": "bg",
        "created_at": "Tue Feb 11 15:53:41 +0000 2014",
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "place": null,
        "metadata": {
            "iso_language_code": "bg",
            "result_type": "recent"
        }
    }
]
```

When I run the file, I am getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/Users/Piyush/Desktop/2008/runcsv.py", line 11, in <module>
writer.writerow(data)

_csv.Error: sequence expected
```

Can someone tell me how I can fix. I don't know python very well so I would appreciate if you give me a detailed answer.

Comment: Why not use pandas?

Comment: @selten98 Explain me how to use this?

Comment: `import pandas   
df = pd.DataFrame([])   
df = df.from_json(JSONHERE)   
df.to_csv()`   
Something like this.

Comment: @selten98 try this and received 7 error !!!

Comment: That was just an example and that is multi-line. I just couldn't get it formatted correctly.

Comment: @selten98 i know it syntax and write correctly but i think this work is not easy like that !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested Json to pandas DataFrame with specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341974/nested-json-to-pandas-dataframe-with-specific-format)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("FILE.json")
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

This code might work for you.

Comment: this is a very simple code and not worked for me ! my json structure is complex...