# Python Pandas, one dict column, create new rows for each key/value pair

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with about 500000 lines in the following format:

```
**ID  Name  Tags**
4345  Bill  {'circle:blue', 'background:orange', 'Type':12}
```

For more straightforward data analysis I would like to convert to:

```
**ID   Name  Key         Value** 
4345   Bill  Circle      Blue
4345   Bill  Background  Orange
4345   Bill  Type        12
```

I have found an answer that can split one key/value per row:
[Python Pandas: How to split a sorted dictionary in a column of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742975/python-pandas-how-to-split-a-sorted-dictionary-in-a-column-of-a-dataframe), but I have failed miserably to extend this to perform my requirement above.

I could probably manage this with some standard loops, but I'm hoping there's an elegant and efficient Pandas approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266225/1744834), you can do something similar:

```
>>> df_tags = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Tags']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=False)
>>> df_tags.columns = ['Key', 'Value']
>>> df_tags
          Key   Value
0        Type      12
0  background  orange
0      circle    blue
>>> df.drop('Tags', axis=1).join(df_tags)
     ID  Name         Key   Value
0  4345  Bill        Type      12
0  4345  Bill  background  orange
0  4345  Bill      circle    blue
```

Comment: The solution worked very well with a small test data set, but my computer went into meltdown on a 0.5M row table.  I've reverted to doing this in Postgresql and importing the results to Pandas.