# Maximum and Minimum Value of a Dictonary Using Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries:

```
l_dict = [{'start': 2, 'length': 2, 'end': 4}, {'start': 1, 'length': 5, 'end': 8}, {'start': 3, 'length': 2, 'end': 7}, {'start': 3, 'length': 1, 'end': 3}, {'start': 2, 'length': 1, 'end': 2}, {'start': 1, 'length': 4, 'end': 5}, {'start': 1, 'length': 5, 'end': 9}, {'start': 3, 'length': 1, 'end': 3}, {'start': 1, 'length': 5, 'end': 6}, {'start': 1, 'length': 3, 'end': 3}, {'start': 1, 'length': 2, 'end': 2}, {'start': 1, 'length': 3, 'end': 5}, {'start': 4, 'length': 1, 'end': 4}, {'start': 1, 'length': 4, 'end': 4}, {'start': 1, 'length': 1, 'end': 1}, {'start': 1, 'length': 4, 'end': 6}]
```

How can I find the dict in the list with greatest 'length' and minimum 'start' and maximum 'end' entry?

Comment: i just tried min or max (l_dict, key=lambda x:x[key]) i don't have an idea how to combine the three

Comment: Well I don't have any idea what you mean by "combine the three". Seems to me you're looking for three separate bits of information. If that's not correct, you need to revise your Q to clarify what you're actually trying to do, and like, what is the expected/correct output if given this list of dict.

Comment: the output need to be dict with minimum start value and maximum end value and greater length that is {'start': 1, 'length': 5, 'end': 9}

Comment: What would be the output of `[{'start': 1, 'length': 5, 'end': 9}, {'start': 1, 'length': 6, 'end': 8}`?   If start/length/end are not related in such a way like (end == start+length) that you can discard one of the criteria, I don't know how this is going to possible, because you have three criteria for three independent variables, each of which can conflict with others: rock beats scissors but scissors beats paper but paper beats rock...

Comment: @DavidZemens u r right :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get key with the least value from a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282823/get-key-with-the-least-value-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you can sort by the properties you need and take the first element.

```
l_dict = [{'start': 2, 'length': 2, 'end': 4}, {'start': 1, 'length': 5, 'end': 8}, {'start': 3, 'length': 2, 'end': 7}, {'start': 3, 'length': 1, 'end': 3}, {'start': 2, 'length': 1, 'end': 2}, {'start': 1, 'length': 4, 'end': 5}, {'start': 1, 'length': 5, 'end': 9}, {'start': 3, 'length': 1, 'end': 3}, {'start': 1, 'length': 5, 'end': 6}, {'start': 1, 'length': 3, 'end': 3}, {'start': 1, 'length': 2, 'end': 2}, {'start': 1, 'length': 3, 'end': 5}, {'start': 4, 'length': 1, 'end': 4}, {'start': 1, 'length': 4, 'end': 4}, {'start': 1, 'length': 1, 'end': 1}, {'start': 1, 'length': 4, 'end': 6}]
l_dict_sorted = sorted(l_dict, key=lambda x: (-x['length'],x['start'],-x['end']))
l_dict_sorted
```

Comment: huge amount of data is there, so i just want a better way to reduce loading time,any suggestions ?

Comment: you should say in which format is your data initially stored beside that maximum is a linear operation while sorting is a n*log(n) operation

Answer (score 1):

Using generators to do this is preferable... And I am throwing in a lambda as they are excellent for one liners.

```
getExtremum = lambda seq, attr, minmax: minmax(d[attr] for d in seq)

max_length = getExtremum(l_dict, 'length', max)
min_start = getExtremum(l_dict, 'start', min)
max_end = getExtremum(l_dict, 'end', max)
```

Comment: Nice, but it scans the whole list for every item, O(3N). It would be interesting to time it against a single `for` loop. The OP says the list is huge