# How can i find the minimum value and key in a scipy dictionary of keys?

Tags: python, scipy, kdtree

I'm trying to find the shortest distance between 2 kd trees and am using the scipy function 'sparse_distance_matrix'. The result is returned in a dictionary of keys matrix of the form `{(1,2):4.54}`.

Its possible to retrieve the value using the following code but no method seems to work to get the key value since its in tuple form

```
sparsemin = sp.KDTree.sparse_distance_matrix(aKD,bKD,20)
m = min(sparsemin.itervalues())
```

Comment: The top votes answer to the proposed duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282823/get-key-with-the-least-value-from-a-dictionary, does not work here.  This is a `sparse.dok` matrix; which is a subclass of dictionary.  It has its own `get` method.

Answer (score 1):

`min(sparsemin.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0]))` will return a tuple with the minimum value and its key.

```
a = {(1,2): 2.54, (1, 0): 4.52}
min(a.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0]))
>> ((1, 2), 2.54)
```

Comment: Or somewhat easier, `min(a, key=a.get)`. (It will only return the key.  Getting the value given the key is left as an exercise to the reader.)

Comment: This `a.get` is the top answer to the supposed duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282823/get-key-with-the-least-value-from-a-dictionary.  It works in that case, but not here.  `IndexError: index must be a pair of integers`.

Comment: This is a sparse `dok` dictionary; implemented as a subclass of the regular dictionary.