# Return key associated with min value of a dict if min key is not in set

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have a dictionary and a set. I want to return the key associated with the minimum value if that key is not already in the set without creating a second dictionary used to delete items that are already in the set.

Example: I have dictionary

```
d = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:40}
```

and a set

```
s = set([1,2])
```

It should return 3

Comment: so make a dictionary that only contains the key:values that are not in the set and return the minimum of that, what is the issue.

Comment: I did that I just wanted to know if there was another way to do it that did not involve making another dictionary.

Comment: Apart from having to construct/filter for keys not in s, this is a **near-duplicate of [Get key with the least value from a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282823/get-key-with-the-least-value-from-a-dictionary)**

Comment: I had seen that question but the added filter was the part I was asking for help on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the set operations to subtract the set `s` from the set of keys of `d`, then use `min` with `key=d.get` to get the remaining key with the smallest value:

```
d = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:40}
s = set([1,2])

print min(set(d) - s, key=d.get)
```

prints `3`

If the result must be `None` when no key was found use:

```
q = set(d) - s
print min(q, key=d.get) if q else None
```

Rather than the `ValueError` from `min`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `min` with generator expression that returns keys not in `s` and key parameter that gets the value from `d`:

```
>>> d = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:40}
>>> s = set([1,2])
>>> min((k for k in d if k not in s), key=d.get)
3
```

Above approach wouldn't create any intermediate containers. In case there's a possibility that `s` matches keys from `d` default value can be used:

```
>>> d = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:40}
>>> s = set([1,2,3,4])
>>> min((k for k in d if k not in s), key=d.get, default=-1)
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Set operations work nicely here.

```
d = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:40}
s = set([1,2])

def find_min(d, s):
    keys = set(d)
    difference = keys-s
    return min(difference) if difference else None

>>> print find_min(d, s)
3
```

alternatively, you could have `difference = filter(lambda e: e not in s, d)`

Comment: Note that `set(d) != s` will fail when `s - set(d)` is non-empty. The condition should be `set(d) - s`. Consider `set([0])` or `set([1,2,3,4,5])`.

Comment: Good catch! Updated.