# getting minimum (key, value) in a list that holds a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, min

I have a list that holds a dictionary row like this:

```
queue = [{1: 0.39085439023582913, 2: 0.7138416909634645, 3: 0.9871959077954673}]
```

I'm tryin to get it to return the smallest value along with its key, so in this case it would return

```
1,0.39085439023582913
```

I've tried using

```
min(queue, key=lambda x:x[1])
```

but that just returns the whole row like this: any suggestions? thank you!

```
{1: 0.39085439023582913, 2: 0.7138416909634645, 3: 0.9871959077954673}
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282823/get-the-key-corresponding-to-the-minimum-value-within-a-dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the min for each dict in the list, you can use the following list comprehension:

```
[min(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]) for d in queue]
```

Which for your example returns:

```
[(1, 0.39085439023582913)]
```

`d.items()` returns a list of tuples in the form `(key, value)` for the dictionary `d`. We then sort these tuples using the value (`x[1]` in this case).

If you always have your data in the form of a list with one dictionary, you could also call `.items()` on the first element of `queue` and find the min:

```
print(min(queue[0].items(), key=lambda x:x[1]))
#(1, 0.39085439023582913)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `min(queue)` will find minimum in the `list` and not in the enclosed `dictionary`
Do this:

```
key_of_min_val = min(queue[0], key=queue[0].get)
print((key_of_min_val , queue[0][key_of_min_val]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it through

```
mykey = min(queue[0], key=queue[0].get)
```

then just use this key and get your dictionary value

```
mykey, queue[0][mykey]
```

Comment: Queue is a list