# Retrieve keys corresponding to minimum value in nested dict of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, minimum

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282823/get-the-key-corresponding-to-the-minimum-value-within-a-dictionary?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) explains how to get the key corresponding to a minium value in a dictionary.

How would you extend this to get the **keys** of the minimum value in a dict of dicts?

For example, say we have a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
d = {
     3: {5: 0.6, 37: 0.98, 70: 0.36},
     5: {5: 2.67, 37: 0.01, 70: 0.55},
     7: {5: 0.2, 37: 0.3, 70: 1.2}
    }
```

How can I obtain the keys (5,37) of the outer and inner dictionaries respectively corresponding to the minimum value of 0.01? Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to restructure your dictionary and use a list comprehension to retrieve the keys with minimum value:

```
d = {
     3: {5: 0.6, 37: 0.98, 70: 0.36},
     5: {5: 2.67, 37: 0.01, 70: 0.55},
     7: {5: 0.2, 37: 0.3, 70: 1.2}
    }

res_dict = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    for k2, v2 in v.items():
        res_dict[(k, k2)] = v2

minval = min(res_dict.values())
res = [k for k, v in res_dict.items() if v == minval]

print(res)
# [(5, 37)]
```

Comment: You never use your `v` variable. You can use `v` instead of `d[k]`. But more importantly, why not invert the dict and swap keys with values? You'd change `res_dict[(k, k2)] = v2` to `res_dict[v2] = (k, k2)` and then `minval = min(res_dict)` and `res = res_dict[minval]`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, First point noted - thank you. Second point, what if there are multiple key combinations with the same value? Then you need to build a `defaultdict` of lists. Entirely possible, but may be overkill.

Comment: Ah, I see, your code lists all keys with the minimum value. I assumed it'd be enough to return just one of the keys with the minum value, if there are multiple.