# argmin for nested dict in python

Tags: python

I have a dict of dict object. What is the best way to find keys associating with the min value of the object?
For example:

```
myDict = {'a': {'n': 1, 'm' : 2, 'l' : 3}, 'b':{'m' = 2, 'l': 3, 'k':4}}
(firstKey, secondKey) = argmin(myDict)
```

The argmin should return 'a' and 'n'
What I am doing now is:

```
minValue = 10
firstKey, secondKey = None, None
for k1 in myDict.keys():
    for k2 in myDict[k1].keys():
        if myDict[k1][k2] < minValue:
            minValue = myDict[k1][k2]
            firstKey, secondKey = k1, k2
```

Comment: Do you only expect the first minimum or all minima to be returned?

Comment: the first one only.

Answer (score 0):

This works and leaves most work to python build ins:

```
def helper(k_d):
    key, d = k_d
    mi = min(d, key=d.get)
    v = d[mi]
    return ((key, mi), v)

d = {'a': {'n': 1, 'm': 2, 'l': 3}, 'b': {'m': 2, 'l': 3, 'k': 4}}
min_dict = dict(map(helper, d.items()))
result = min(min_dict, key=min_dict.get)
```

This is build around this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3282904/2376882). Helper will take a tuple of key and dict, find the key (`mi`) of the passed dict with the minimal value and return it along with the value (`v`) and the first-level key (`key`).

Answer (score 0):

This will work for both `keys`

```
my_dict = {'a': {'n': 1, 'm' : 2, 'l' : 3}, 'b':{'m': 2, 'l': 3, 'k':4}}

smallest = {i: min(my_dict[i].values()) for i in my_dict}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    print(k, *[i for i in v if v[i] == smallest[k]])

# a n
# b m
```