# return key of minimum value

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to return the key of the minimum value in a `dictionary` in Python. The value of key, value pair will have several numbers, i.e. `dict[current] = (total, gone, heuristic)`. How can I return the key of minimum gone value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the key corresponding to the minimum value within a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282823/get-the-key-corresponding-to-the-minimum-value-within-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `min` with a lambda lookup function:

```
min(d, key=lambda k: d[k][1])
```

Comment: Can we use `itemgetter` here?

Comment: I dont why, this returns 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @Ayesha are you using round brackets instead of square ones?

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through the dictionary

```
best = None
for key, t in d.items():
    if best is None or t[1] < d[best][1]:
        best = key
return best
```

Comment: think it should be `tuple[1] < dict[best]`

Comment: @Stuart yes you are right! Thank you

Comment: `dict`, `tuple` are keywords, use `d` and `t` instead.

Comment: I am getting IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: Sorry had a typo. Basically `best` keeps track of the best key seen. Then for each tuple compare its gone value (the value at index 1) to the gone value of the best and if it is better then update `best`

Answer (score 0):

Simply, iterate through the dictionary:

```
d = {1: (1,2,3), 2: (2,4,5), 4: (5,0,2)}
best = None
mn = 99999999 # if you have values more than this, then use float('inf') instead
for k in d:
    if mn > d[k][1]:
        mn = d[k][1]
        best = k 
print(best)
# Output: 4
```