# How can I filter a python dictionary by minimum value and return a new dict of values above the min value?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

How would I filter a dictionary based on a minimum value?

```
grades = {"Bob": 46, "Angela":73, "Dave": 94}
```

I want to make a new dictionary that is only people with values above 70.

```
passing = {"Angela":73, "Dave":94}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the key corresponding to the minimum value within a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282823/get-the-key-corresponding-to-the-minimum-value-within-a-dictionary)

Comment: Not quite, no, I wanted all values that were above a filter like when you filter a list with something like [num for num in numbers if num > 70] but with a dictionary instead. I changed the question details and title and got some answers about dictionary comprehensions. Thanks for feedback that got me to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not that complex, just follow this and you are good to go. We can do it by two ways

1. Using Dictionary Comprehension. Follow [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-comprehension/) to know more about it

```
grades = {"Bob": 46, "Angela":73, "Dave": 94}

# new dictionary to get what you want
# using dictionary comprehension in python
passing = {key:value for key, value in grades.items() if value > 70}

print(passing)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'Angela': 73, 'Dave': 94}
```

2. Using normal approach

```
grades = {"Bob": 46, "Angela":73, "Dave": 94}

passing = {}

# traversing through dictionary items
for key, value in grades.items():
   # check for passing values
   if value > 70: passing[key] = value

print(passing)
```

Output will be same. What I'd suggest that start learning about `Dictionary Comprehension`, it is more convenient, and cleaner way to code. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

Try a dict comprehension to filter grades greater than 70:

```
>>> grades = {"Bob": 46, "Angela":73, "Dave": 94}
>>> {k: v for k, v in grades.items() if v > 70}
{'Angela': 73, 'Dave': 94}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use dictionary comprehension. 
Store the new dictionary in the same variable

```
grades = {k:v for k,v in grades.items() if v > 70}
```

Store the new dictionary in another variable

```
another = {k:v for k,v in grades.items() if v > 70}
```

Output:

```
{'Angela': 73, 'Dave': 94}
```