# Return key corresponding to the tuple with smallest third value from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, min

I am trying to return the key corresponding to the tuple with smallest third index value from a dictionary of tuples (a `namedtuple` vertex as key and a tuple with 3 elements as value).

For example, suppose I have the tuple:

```
vertex = namedtuple("Vertex", ["vertex_id", "vertex_x", "vertex_y"])
d = {vertex(vertex_id='B', vertex_x=11, vertex_y=0): (4, 5, 9), 
        vertex(vertex_id='C', vertex_x=6, vertex_y=0): (2, 0, 2), 
        vertex(vertex_id='A', vertex_x=4, vertex_y=0): (0, 2, 3)}
```

I need something to return me `Vertex(vertex_id='C', vertex_x=6, vertex_y=0)`. I was trying something like `min(d.values(), key = lambda t: t[2])` (but this returns the tuple `(2, 0, 2)` and I would have to trace it back to its key) or `min(d, key = lambda t: t[2])` (this isn't really working).

Is there a better way to set min() to do this or do I have to trace back the key corresponding to the value that the first way gives me? It would be more efficient if I don't have to search for it when working with larger dictionaries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the key corresponding to the minimum value within a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282823/get-the-key-corresponding-to-the-minimum-value-within-a-dictionary)

Comment: No, my case requires a different custom of the key parameter which i'm not really familiar with. I've checked this question before, in fact, the solution I tried is based on its top answer and some others questions.

Comment: Andrej Kesely's answer below uses the exact form of the second highest rated answer to the existing question and shows how to make it work for your particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min()` with custom `key=` function. You can search the minimum over the tuples of `d.items()`:

```
print( min(d.items(), key=lambda k: k[1][2])[0] )
```

Prints:

```
Vertex(vertex_id='C', vertex_x=6, vertex_y=0)
```

Comment: Why `k[1][2] ]` ? What does the `[1]` access?

Comment: @DaviMagalhães `d.items()` returns tuples in format `( (key1, items1), (key2, items2) ... )`, so  index `[1]` locates the item in these tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not intended to be used that way. You should not attempt to trace a value back to a key.
Try this instead:

```
keys = list(d.keys())
k = keys[0]
m = d[k]
for v in keys[1:]:
    if d[v][2] < m[2]:
        k = v
        m = d[k]
```

The vertex key you want will be in k.

Answer (score 0):

If using a dict is not mandatory for you, I think the code below is the right way to go.
Anyway  - you can see a modern NamedTuple example.

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Vertex(NamedTuple):
  id:str
  x:int
  y:int

class Triple(NamedTuple):
  first:int
  second:int
  third:int

class Pair(NamedTuple):
  vertex: Vertex
  triple: Triple


pairs = [Pair(Vertex('B',11,0),Triple(4,5,9)),Pair(Vertex('C',6,0),Triple(2,0,2)),Pair(Vertex('A',4,0),Triple(0,2,3))]
_min = min(pairs,key=lambda p: p.triple.third)
print(_min.vertex)
```